# how to make electron with next js 13.4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, electron, vite

I'm diving into a new project and I want to build a desktop application using Next.js 13.4 and Electron. But I couldn't find any boilerplates for this combo. I did give Vite a shot, but no luck there either.

I would greatly appreciate any recommendations or suggestions on how to approach this project. Are there any existing boilerplates that I might have missed? Or perhaps there are alternative frameworks or tools that work better with Next.js 13.4 and Electron?

Comment: You probably won't find anything because it's too new, but I would say that whatever electron offers in terms of being a "backend", next really already has. So I wonder if you really need electron vs just a next app that launches a browser window.

Comment: you can use this template - https://github.com/saltyshiomix/nextron